# Move dygraphs pop-up label

Tags: dygraphs

When I hover over points on a line in my dygraph chart a nice thing pops up and shows me the X and Y position along with what column in my CSV is represented by the Y point. This is by default.

The pop-up text is way on the top left of my graph and intersects with the Y axis. How can I move it to the right? I can't figure out how because I don't know what the pop-up is called.

The initialization is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.0.0/dygraph.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.0.0/dygraph.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="graphdiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g2 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
    "file.csv", 
  );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The file is as follows:

```
Timestamp,Value
2017-01-01T00:00,12345
```

Comment: Could you add some code? The initialization of your dygraph could be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this in your css

```
.dygraph-legend { 
   text-align: right; 
   background: none; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a solution.

Comment: Good!! Accept this answer and I'm going to remove the other as it  was not helpful for you ;) Regards!